# CryptoSwift used by two private third-party frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have two private frameworks (3rd party) that use CryptoSwift.

Framework 1 suggests installing with cocoapods while Framework 2 suggests using carthage.

When installing with cocoapods, Framework 2 throws the below error at run time on the device:
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s11CryptoSwift7PaddingO5pkcs7yA2CmFWC

Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/94E49A38-E3C0-4CDB-8EE7-D49767C0630F/Redacted/Frameworks/Framework1.framework/FMService

Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/94E49A38-E3C0-4CDB-8EE7-D49767C0630F/Redacted/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/94E49A38-E3C0-4CDB-8EE7-D49767C0630F/Redacted/Frameworks/Framework1.framework/FMService

The same is thrown from framework 2 when using carthage to install CryptoSwift:
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s11CryptoSwift7PaddingO5pkcs7yA2CmFWC

Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/94E49A38-E3C0-4CDB-8EE7-D49767C0630F/Redacted/Frameworks/Framework2.framework/GWService

Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/94E49A38-E3C0-4CDB-8EE7-D49767C0630F/Redacted/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/94E49A38-E3C0-4CDB-8EE7-D49767C0630F/Redacted/Frameworks/Framework2.framework/GWService

Answer (score 0):

This is a transitive dependency problem caused by the fact that different dependency managers (Cocoapods and Carthage) don't know about each other dependency graph and try to link the same framework twice. I don't think there's an easy solution out of the box other than

a) use a single dependency manager

b) manually setup all dependencies